# how to change the back ground color of the entire row in a data table when the check box is selected using css in jsp?

Tags: java, css, ajax, jsf, primefaces

The below is the jsp page code:

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" exportable="false" style="text-
align:center;">
</p:column>
  <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update="deleteButton"/>
  <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update="deleteButton"/>
```

And now the default background color is showing which blue, but I want to make it gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your valuable answers.

I did overwrite "ui-state-highlight, ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight" CSS tag , And it did work .

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update="deleteEntry" 
rowClasses="ui-state-highlight, ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight" />
```

Comment: The code above is weird... rowClasses on an ajax tag? And 'accepting' the good answer (the existing one) is common practice in Stakoverflow

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, overwrite the default ui-state-highlight class that is applied to the row (tr element) once it is selected.

```
ui-datatable-selectable.ui-state-highlight{
    background-color: gray
}
```

Comment: So what you effectively say is OP should learn some basic css and learn how to use browser developer tools to insoect the css that is applied

Comment: Maybe you could show an example to him how to handle the event on the client side to change the css class property value in it.

Comment: @thebitman: you don't need to add a class is added by PF, no need for proceaaing evemts. You just need to add the css.